# Can I run my own instance of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, centos

I'm trying to migrate a web site to friend's server.  The site uses MySQL, but he didn't previously have it set up.  He's installed the package now and suggested that I could run my own instance of it.  I'm at a loss for how to do so.  Is it even possible?  If so, how?

Some relevant information:

- The OS in use is CentOS 5.9
- Using MySQL 5.0.95
- I only need the DB to be read locally via PHP when serving my site.
- I have no root privileges on this system (although a full shell), but am close friends with the owner/administrator if that's necessary.

To clarify:
It's the daemon that I want to run my own instance of.  So I guess what I want to know is if it's possible to have multiple users on the system running their own instances of mysqld containing different databases.

All I need this for is serving a web page.  If I have to break down and switch to a pseudo-database using CSV files I will, but I'd much rather stick to MySQL if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MYSQL is setup on that machine yes you can run your own instance of it.

You can have it set up and your site given its on Database within that MYSQL instance and that specific MYSQL account can be used to access the tables etc. involved with your website.

Now if he is only putting MYSQL on the machine then having you set everything up you will just need an account for MYSQL and from ther eyou can get in and just create all the needed items that will allow your site to fully function.

**EDIT**
In response to your comment. You can you just can't clog the same port or have configurations that conflict each other. As long as it won't be to much of a performance hit and you configure a different user to start each instance you should be able to do [Something like this.](http://tipstricks.itmatrix.eu/?p=557&cpage=1)

Comment: Sorry, to clarify here, I mean to ask if I can run my own instance of the daemon, not just clients.  If that still is applicable, is there any good documentation you could point me to?  I'll expand my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Jacob Ewing See Edit